# Change values in first key from 0 to count(array) - 1

Tags: php, arrays

Ok, I have an array like so:

```
$myArray[32]['value'] = 'value1';
$myArray[32]['type'] = 'type1';
$myArray[33]['value'] = 'value2';
$myArray[33]['type'] = 'type2';
$myArray[35]['value'] = 'value3';
$myArray[42]['value'] = 'value4';
$myArray[42]['type'] = 'type4';
```

Ok, looking for a quick way to change all numbers in the first key 32, 33, 35, and 42 into 0, 1, 2, and 3 instead.  But I need to preserve the 2nd key and all of the values.  The array is already ordered correctly, since I ordered it using a ksort, but now I need to reset the array from 0 - count($myArray) - 1 and keep the 2nd key intact and its value as well.

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$myArray = array_values($myArray);
```

Comment: Thanks this works, didn't know that using array_values would keep the 2nd key index intact as well.

CHEERS :)

Answer (score 0):

There might be simpler solutions but here is one working solution:

```
$myArray = array();
$myArray[32]['value'] = 'value1';
$myArray[32]['type'] = 'type1';
$myArray[33]['value'] = 'value2';
$myArray[33]['type'] = 'type2';
$myArray[35]['value'] = 'value3';
$myArray[42]['value'] = 'value4';
$myArray[42]['type'] = 'type4';

$map = array_flip(array_keys($myArray)); // map old keys to new keys.
$newarray = array();
foreach($myArray as $key => $value) {
    $newarray[$map[$key]] = $value; // use new key and old value.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need it. Why not to just leave this array alone? Unnecessary moves would lead your code to a mess.

Comment: because the 1st key index is linked to an id that I don't want others to be able to have access to for security reasons!

Comment: @sologhost who forces you to print keys out? Ever tried to think before doing?

Comment: HA HA, well sure, I have tried this, I'm just tired from thinking so much already that I'm experiencing Brain Farts...lol

Comment: And furthermore, I need to get the id as the first key so that it can be sorted by id value using ksort().  IT MUST BE SORTED.  But after sorting it, I am returning it into an array that others will have access to.  So it needs to be 0 indexed.

Comment: @sologhost Users don't have access to your arrays.